# Interpreting ACF and Partial ACF Plots with Python

Tags: time-series, python, acf-pacf

I have time series data which is measured in each 5 second. I am trying to forecast the data. But, ACF and PACF results are seems to different than other plot that I have seen. I am using statsmodels as a library like below.

```
from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_pacf
plot_pacf(ts, lags = 40, method = "ols");

from statsmodels.graphics.tsaplots import plot_acf
plot_acf(ts, lags = 50);
```

[image]

[image]

What I need to interpret with these plots?

Comment: Your series might have a unit root. What does *sn* stand for?

Comment: Hi Richard, I fixed it. Measurements happens in each 5 second.

Comment: With the ADF test, I can said that data is non-stationary. But, Is the PACF, ACF reasonable for the unit root case?

Comment: Yes, a unit root process may produce ACF and PACF that look like yours.